# Strange error with Spring form tag for date

Tags: spring, forms, jsp

I have

```
public class FormInputValidationTest {

private String email;
private Date dob;
private String doj;
private String desig;
```

and associated getters/setters

and my HomeController (just the one controller) is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/validation", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String new_validation(Locale locale, Model model) {
    FormInputValidationTest fivt = new FormInputValidationTest();
    logger.info("in validation for GET request");
    model.addAttribute("fivt",fivt);
    return "validation";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/validation", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String new_validation(@ModelAttribute("fivt") FormInputValidationTest fivt, Locale locale, Model model, HttpServletRequest req) {
    logger.info("in validation for POST request");
    logger.info("email received from user input is : {}",fivt.getEmail());
//  logger.info("dob received from user input is : {}",fivt.getDob().toString());
    logger.info("desig received from user input is : {}",fivt.getDesig());
    logger.info("doj received from user input is : {}",fivt.getDoj());
    model.addAttribute("message","successfully added");
    return new_validation(locale, model);
}
```

and finally my view is

```
   <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
   <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
     pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
   <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
   <%@ page session="false"%>
    <html>
    <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <title>Search/View</title>
     </head>
     <body>
        <h1></h1>
      <!-- modelAttribute="fivt" -->
     <form:form method="post" action="validation" commandName="fivt" accept-charset="utf-8">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="email">Email</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="email" /></td>
        </tr>
         <!--   <tr> -->
         <%--   <td><form:label path="dob">DB</form:label></td> --%>
         <%--   <td><form:input path="dob" /></td> --%>
         <!--   </tr> -->
            <tr>
            <td><form:label path="doj">DOJ</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="doj" /></td>
        </tr>           
        <tr>
            <td><form:label path="desig">Desig</form:label></td>
            <td><form:input path="desig" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>    
        </form:form>
     </body>
     </html>
```

I have commented out the form:input path = "dob"
because when i have this as an input in my page and submit with proper values or not
I always get a 400 status response

```
     type Status report

     message

     description The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect.
```

It works fine without "dob" as input 
i have been trying to look at request headers and body but i still havent been able to understand why that is giving me some problems.
So I added the doj (date expected) but declared as String to test and that seems fine

Could someone throw some light on this?
especially since this code (I havent tried) seems to be able to handle input for a Date object in its associated model.

PS: its the same even if I use modelAttribute="fivt" in the form tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a form is submitted its values are of type String. Now when you write "Date dob" what spring tries to do is assign String value to Date variable which is not possible. The correct way of doing it is by using @DateTimeFormat annotation over date variable to tell spring to convert incoming String value to its corresponding Date value.

Refer [this](http://gerrydevstory.com/2013/05/21/binding-date-form-input-on-spring-mvc/) post

Comment: Prabhat.. thanx for the response.. I have been able to work past that making sure the date is in yyyy/mm/dd format for the time being..